# How to Append image using Json

Tags: php, json

I am creating an e-commerce site. i ran into the problem of displaying image on home page. all relevant data have displayed success. the only image couldn't be displayed.I didn't get any errors while checking the console. 
what i tried so far i attached below.

**Json**   `**$("#Products").append("<img id='theImg' src='images/'  + data[i].image  + ' />'");**`  this is image append code i written.

```
   function getProducts(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'all_product.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    $("#Products").append("<img id='theImg' src='images/'  + data[i].image  + ' />'");
                    $('#Products').append('<h5>' + data[i].description +  '</h5>');
                    $('#Products').append('<p>' + data[i].price +  '</p>');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

**all_product.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,cat_id,brand_id,price,description,image,keywords from products order by id DESC");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$cat_id,$brand_id,$price,$description,$image,$keywords);

if($stmt->execute())
{
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $output[] = array("id"=>$id, "cat_id" =>$cat_id, "brand_id"=> $brand_id,"price"=> $price, "description"=> $description,
            "image"=> $image, "keywords"=> $keywords);
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}

$stmt->close();
?>
```

**Design**

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" id="Products">
                    <img id="theImg">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If the below answer doesn't work, can you do `console.log(data[i].image);` at some point and verify that it's actually your image name that's in there? And if that variable is not what you expect it to be, do a `error_log($image)` in PHP in the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the code as following. You are missing a a double qoutes which makes variable as stirng.

```
$("#Products").append("<img id='theImg' src='images/"  + data[i].image  + "' class='your-css-class' />");
```

Comment: What does the line `console.log(data);` show in console ?@creativeone2018

Comment: yes sir. brand_id: 3
cat_id: 1
description: "caps only"
id: 2
image: "2.jpg"
keywords: "caps"
price: 200

Comment: i think problem in img tag sir. is there any error on img tag

Comment: right click the image blank and check with console result show like this <img id="theImg" src="images/" 2.jpg'="">

Comment: @creativeone2018 copy my answer and replace it with yours. There was some qoutes extra

Comment: Give a class to the image tag as in my answer and apply css in your style sheet@creativeone2018

Comment: css can you help me sir

Comment: Do you have a style sheet ?@creativeone2018

Comment: i haven't wrote it.

Comment: Then just create a `.css` file like `mystyles.css` and add it to your page. Inside that write your css as `img.your-class-name{ width:100px;height:100px;display:block;}`

Comment: @creativeone2018 You are always welcome .Feel free to ask if you need help with image styling. Have a good day

Comment: if i get more doubt about php how can i contact you your are best programmer