# How to get my web page to display images from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm new to web development. In my `index.html`, I have the following two images:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
   <a href="placeholder.com">
      <img class=rounded src="placeholder.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="placeholder.com">
      <img class=rounded src="placeholder.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

and in my js file I have a function that gets an image and page link:

```js
let randomImgAndLink = function() {
   let url = 'api-site.org/123'
   fetch(url)
      .then(response => { return response.json(); })
      .then(json => {
          img = json.imgpath
          page = json.pagepath
      })
}
```

How would I get the images and webpages from this function into the `placeholder`? And how would I do this without a `placeholder`? I would like to implement this with DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002352/how-to-append-image-using-json

Comment: you can put your JavaScript function in <script> tag and fetch the url in java script using the variable

Answer (score 0):

Add onload call function, to call on result of JavaScript function. E.g,
onload="javascript:showImage();">

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the img element from your html into the JavaScript using document.getElement or query selector and set it’s src to your fetch result. I hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please improve your answer by bringing some codes to show how it should be done.